# Pre-Charge / Authorization for PoS API

Tags: square, square-connect

trying to do the following:

1. The user comes in to register / check-in
2. Swipe credit card to gain access
3. Upon leaving / check-out they are charged a certain amount based on the length of time they have stayed. No human interaction.

Similar to the the garage parking lot experiences.

With Square PoS it requires the "amount to be charged". Is there a way to get the user Credit Card information when they swipe upon entering, save that info (with a pre charge, etc.) and then charge it when they leave?

Other options include precharging a higher amount and then doing a return for the amount of time not used but that seems messy.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't authorize without making a charge with the Point of Sale API.

You could charge them a small fee for signing in, store that card on file, and then charge them again when they leave. Or you could use the REST APIs to let people add their card on file online, and then they wouldn't need to swipe at all during sign-in. With the REST APIs you can also do a [delayed capture](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/overview#delayed-capture-transactions) transaction.